# Listview is overlapping app bar layout

Tags: android, listview, android-coordinatorlayout

Im using the following code to create a collapsing toolbar containing listview below it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/love_music"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/backdrop_title"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/backdrop_title" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/backdrop_subtitle"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/backdrop_subtitle" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/activity_experience"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"  />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The problem is that, the listview is overlapping with appbar layout and hence the listview appears within appbarlayout. The layout `activity_experience` contains the listview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CoordinatorLayout`  won't work like RelativeLayout.
 This is why `android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"`  isn't working properly for you.

Instead add this to your `layout="@layout/activity_experience"`:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

Comment: still the same problem is existing